# The "standard" definition of discrete subspace

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $D\subset X$ a generic subspace. In literature I have found the following different definitions:

1. $D$ is *discrete* in $X$ if $X$ doesn't contain limit points of $D$.
2. $D$ is *discrete* in $X$ if every point of $D$ is isolated respect to $X$.

Clearly $1.\Rightarrow 2.$, but the converse it is not true. Consider for example 
$$D=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\,: n\in\mathbb N\, \right\}\subset\mathbb C$$
Every point of $D$ is isolated, but $0$ is a limit point of $D$.

Which of the above definitions is the most used to characterize discrete sets?

Comment: I believe u meant #2 to be “with respect to the subspace topology for D contained in X”. The way it reads now it makes it seem that u are referring to singleton open sets as open in the topology on X

Comment: They would be equivalent if 1 where ‘if D doesnt contain limit points of D’.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience as a general and set-theoretic topologist, *discrete* normally just means that the set is discrete in its relative topology; that’s your second alternative. Sets satisfying the first condition are *closed, discrete sets*.