# Kuratowski counterexample

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Say that a set $X⊆\mathbb{R}^2$ is discrete if every point $x\in\mathbb R^2$ has a neighborhood $U$ so that $|U∩X|=1$.  A planar drawing of an infinite graph is a drawing of $G$ where the vertices of $G$ form a discrete set and edges are represented by non-crossing polygonal arcs.  Show that there is an infinite graph on acountable vertex set that cannot be drawn in the plane but has no subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.  (That is Kuratowski’s theorem fails for infinite graphs)

$G$ is said to be planar if it has a planar drawing as described above (in particular separability).

My idea is this. I'm pretty sure it's going to work, but I don't know how to prove it. Essentially swapping two vertices always makes the graph worse.

[image]

Comment: There's no counterexample at all: [Extending Kuratowski's planarity theorem on finite graphs to countable infinite graphs.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705090/extending-kuratowskis-planarity-theorem-on-finite-graphs-to-countable-infinite)

Comment: Their definition of planar is different

Comment: The second answer encompasses all your conditions, in particular the "countably many vertices" condition.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Nope, the question is correct

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, I am afraid you overlooked the condition that "the vertices of G form a *discrete* set". It is easy to construct an example.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Discreteness is implicit in the linked question.

Comment: @Apass.Jack How easy? Could you give a small hint if I'm going in the wrong direction

Comment: @ParclyTaxel In the proof of the other question, we construct an embedding of $G$ by taking the union of compatible embeddings of $G_k$ for all $k$. We could easily end up with vertices at limit points that way.

Comment: The [two definitions of discrete subspace given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486363/the-standard-definition-of-discrete-subspace) might be important.  OP's definition is what I'd write as "closed, discrete subspace", which is stronger than the "discrete" I'd normally assume in planar embeddings.

Comment: I edited to make it a little easier to spot the specialized notion of "discrete set".  That said the "counterexample" proposed in the posted image does not appear to rely on clustering of vertices for its "non-planarity".  I'm effectively voting to leave open because the duplicate target doesn't address the different notion of "discrete set" and the OP shows enough context to convince me the problem statement was digested.

Comment: This question should not be closed as a duplicate since the definitions of "planar graph" in two questions are different. [The comment by Brian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330690#comment9031030_4330690) or [the comment by harmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330690/#comment9032258_4330690) should have clarified the situation. I have raised a flag to ask moderators to reopen this question.

Comment: If I understand your proposed counterexample, it's planar (even under your stronger definition).  What are the crossings between the vertical strands for?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I am disappointed to see that this question is not reopened even after I have raised a flag to reopen this question. Not only the definitions are different in the two questions, the answers are completely opposite. Are you able to reopen this question?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Were you ever convinced that "discrete" is used in a stronger [arguably less common] sense than in your proposed duplicate?  Your push for it to be marked as a duplicate to a closely related but different question has definitely played a role in closing it, and there now doesn't seem to be a route to correct it.

Comment: I think its funny, we should keep it like this. I got the answer so don't worry about dying on the hill for this post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest counterexample I can think of is to take $K_4$ and stick an infinite chain on each vertex.  No matter the planar embedding of $K_4$, one vertex is inside a topological circle, so the connected infinite chain is inside this same bounded set, so the embedding of the vertex set of this chain has a limit point, hence it's not a closed discrete subspace of the plane.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will do.

[image: infinite graph]

Take any square. No matter how you position it on the plane, it must be finite, and each infinite end can be either inside or outside it, and they can't be both outside.

On a side note, using a well-known term in a *subtly* different meaning is generally a bad idea, and the term "planar" in graph theory is used, er, well... more than a little.